# Converting from Long to List[Int]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert a `Long` into a `List[Int]` where each item in the list is a single digit of the original Long.

```
scala> val x: Long = 123412341L
x: Long = 123412341

scala> x.toString.split("").toList
res8: List[String] = List("", 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

scala> val desired = res8.filterNot(a => a == "")
desired: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
```

Using `split("")` results in a `""` list element that I'd prefer not to have in the first place.

I could simply filter it, but is it possible for me to go from `123412341L` to `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)` more cleanly?

Comment: I know Java has a `String.toCharArray` method - could you use that?

Comment: That would not yield their integer values.  For example, the first char in the array would be '1', which has integer value 49.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the integer values of the digits, it can be done like so:

```
scala> x.toString.map(_.asDigit).toList
res65: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
```

Note the difference that the `.map(_.asDigit)` makes:

```
scala> x.toString.toList
res67: List[Char] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

scala> res67.map(_.toInt)
res68: List[Int] = List(49, 50, 51, 52, 49, 50, 51, 52, 49)
```

`x.toString.toList` is a List of Chars, i.e. `List('1','2','3',...)`.  The `toString` rendering of the list makes it look the same, but the two are quite different -- a '1' character, for example, has integer value 49.  Which you should use depends on whether you want the digit characters or the integers they represent.

Comment: I like this answer too. I wasn't aware of the `asDigit` method. So `x.toString` gets implicitly converted to a `StringOps`, which enables the use of `map`

Answer (score 1):

*As pointed out below by Alexey, there are serious problems with this code :\ Don't use it.*

Without using string conversion:

```
def splitDigits(n:Long): List[Int] = {
  n match {
    case 0 => List()
    case _ => {
      val onesDigit = (n%10)
      splitDigits((n-onesDigit)/10) ++ List( onesDigit.toInt )
    }
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
splitDigits(123456789)    //> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
splitDigits(1234567890)   //> res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
splitDigits(12345678900L) //> res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0)
```

The function isn't tail-recursive, but it should work fine for Long values:

```
splitDigits(Long.MaxValue) //> res3: List[Int] = List(9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 0, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7)
```

Comment: It's a bit worse than merely "not tail-recursive", appending lists to the end recursively results in a quadratic algorithm. It's fine when inputs are known to be limited like here, just something to be aware of. It also gives the wrong result for 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and a bit hacky:

```
x.toString.map(_.toString.toInt).toList
```